# Javascript function draw() shape to image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a js script that draws an ellipse and its amplitude based on the volume of the music playing:

```
var song, analyzer;

function preload() {
  song = loadSound('sounds/masterflash.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(250, 250);
  song.loop();

  // create a new Amplitude analyzer
  analyzer = new p5.Amplitude();

  // Patch the input to an volume analyzer
  analyzer.setInput(song);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0, 0)

  // Get the average (root mean square) amplitude
  var rms = analyzer.getLevel();
  fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
  stroke(255, 255, 255);

  // Draw an ellipse with size based on volume
  ellipse(width/3, height/3, 10+rms*200, 10+rms*200);
}
```

You can see a sample of what it does here https://p5js.org/examples/sound-measuring-amplitude.html

You can see on the last code that it creates the ellipse. How can I do the same thing but instead of drawing the ellipse, it loads a round .png image I have?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [preload Image](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) first, and then draw it. More about [`image()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image)

Try like this

```
function preload() { 
  img = loadImage('images/laDefense.jpg');
  song = loadSound('sounds/masterflash.mp3');
}
...

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0, 0)

  // Get the average (root mean square) amplitude
  var rms = analyzer.getLevel();
  fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
  stroke(255, 255, 255);

  image(img, width/3, height/3, 10+rms*200, 10+rms*200);
}
```

Comment: It worked, but now the animation is centered on the upper-left corner instead of the middle. You can see it here over the play button vtxfactory.org

Comment: @Rui I couldn't locate in particular your problem on that website but anyway you can adjust position of image. Just look at the reference how to do it https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image